# How unsafe is coercing typeclass dictionaries?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've got situation where I had a product type (say `T`), and an instance of say `C` derived using `anyclass` deriving, which works because each member of `T` is an instance of `C`.

I changed one member of `T` to a type which wasn't an instance of `C` (lets call the type of this new member `U`). Note that both `C` and `U` are from external libraries, `T` is in my own code. This left me with a few options, that I thought of:

1. Try to manually define an instance `C T`, which would have required me to dig into the generic implementation and basically copy-pasting it.
2. Define an orphan instance `C U` (as I don't control `C` nor `U`).
3. Newtype `U` (say `V U`) and change the member to be of type `V`.

But I didn't really like any of these solutions:

1. I didn't really want to manually copy-paste hack up an entire manual instance of `T` when the Generic derived instance worked quite well.
2. I could make an orphan instance (admittedly I think this is the best approach out of the three) but still, I hear orphans aren't great, as they can increase compile times if they're used deep in an inheritance hierarchy as every module that gets compiles that transitively depends on them has to [check the interface file of the orphan module](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.6.2/docs/users_guide/separate_compilation.html#orphan-modules-and-instance-declarations). Also there's the "orphans are bad" debate.
3. Newtyping just to handle this one instance seems like an overkill. I guess then I could write an accessor that unwraps the newtype, but that doesn't solve everything, like if I want to just unwrap the type using `{}` style syntax I'm still going to have to coerce the result. All this hackery just to handle one pesky instance.

So, what I was thinking is that I just need my custom instance available in this one place, not my whole program.

So I did define a `newtype V = V U`, and defined my instance `C V`. But I DIDN'T change the type `T`. I instead wrote the following function, using the `constraints` library, with some of the ideas I got from [here](https://prophetlabs.de/posts/unsafeCoerceDict.html) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellquestions/comments/sqsu3i/comment/hwpqefv/):

```
import Data.Coerce (Coercible, coerce)
import Data.Constraint qualified as Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Unsafe qualified as Constraint
import Data.Kind (Type)

{-
Given an instance `c b`, this will give you an instance `c a` , so long as `b` is coercible to `a`. 
-}
withLocalInstanceVia :: forall 
  (c :: Type -> Constraint) 
  (a :: Type)
  (b :: Type)
  (r :: Type). 
  (c b, Coercible a b) 
  => (c a => r) -> r
withLocalInstanceVia = Constraint.withDict @(c a) 
  (Constraint.unsafeUnderive (coerce @a @b))
```

And then changed my previous instance like follows:

```
class C a where
  f :: Proxy a -> SomeType

instance C T where
  f = deriveGenericC
```

which currently wasn't compiling because there's no instance `C U`.

To this:

```
instance C T where
  f = withLocalInstanceVia @C @U @V deriveGenericC
```

Which works fine because there IS an instance `C V`.

But of note is that from the `constraints` library I'm using the function [`unsafeUnderive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.13.4/docs/Data-Constraint-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeUnderive). My question is, what exactly is unsafe about `unsafeUnderive`? Here's some concerns:

1. Internally it uses unsafe coerce I believe, but at least unlike [`unsafeCoerceConstraint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.13.4/docs/Data-Constraint-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeCoerceConstraint) it has a coercible constraint. Presumably `unsafeUnderive` is safer than `unsafeCoerceConstraint` but given the name I presume it's still unsafe. Is the unsafety just that future changes in GHC might break such a coercion, or are there some bad ways I could use this today?
2. Any other gotchas here? Presumably all the issues that come with orphan instances (well, aside from the orphan module issue, as the definition is local not global) but given that `V` is defined next to the instance definition and not exported, there really can't be another instance `C V` in scope anyway.

Comment: It's certainly bound to wreak mayhem if you use this with a newtype that already has an instance with different behaviour than the underlying type..

Comment: Would be a good idea to compare with [Coherent explicit dictionary application for Haskell](https://doi.org/10.1145/3242744.3242752)

Comment: If you were interested in strategy 3, I believe you *should* be able to use pattern synonyms to expose a constructor supporting normal pattern matches (including record syntax) in terms of a field of type `U`, while the real type actually has a field of type `V` (and thus can derive an instance). Or (if the parameterisation of `T` allows), you may be able to use `deriving via` to derive an instance for `T`

Comment: Yikes, how did we get from "I heard orphans are bad once" to "how much less unsafe is `unsafeUnderive` than `unsafeCoerceConstraint`?"  I think you should just use an orphan instance.  Unless you have actually demonstrated that there's a significant increase in compile times for your project (which I kind of doubt), or that the usual "orphans are bad" arguments actually apply to your situation (and I can't see how they would), it's not reasonable to go to such extraordinary lengths to avoid a single orphan instance.

Comment: I vote orphan, especially if you are writing an application or an internal library.

Comment: Although... @Ben I think you should gather it up and post as an answer. It looks very promising to me.